# JavaScript equivalent to htonl?

Tags: javascript, network-programming, endianness

For an AJAX request, I need to send a magic number as the first four bytes of the request body, most significant byte first, along with several other (non-constant) values in the request body. Is there something equivalent to htonl in JavaScript?

For example, given 0x42656566, I need to produce the string "Beef". Unfortunately, my number is along the lines of 0xc1ba5ba9. When the server reads the request, it is getting the value -1014906182 (instead of -1044751447).

Comment: This may help: http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/2550-javascript-bit-manipulation.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in function, but something like this should work:

```
// Convert an integer to an array of "bytes" in network/big-endian order.
function htonl(n)
{
    // Mask off 8 bytes at a time then shift them into place
    return [
        (n & 0xFF000000) >>> 24,
        (n & 0x00FF0000) >>> 16,
        (n & 0x0000FF00) >>>  8,
        (n & 0x000000FF) >>>  0,
    ];
}
```

To get the bytes as a string, just call `String.fromCharCode` on each byte and concatenate them:

```
// Convert an integer to a string made up of the bytes in network/big-endian order.
function htonl(n)
{
    // Mask off 8 bytes at a time then shift them into place
    return String.fromCharCode((n & 0xFF000000) >>> 24) +
           String.fromCharCode((n & 0x00FF0000) >>> 16) +
           String.fromCharCode((n & 0x0000FF00) >>>  8) +
           String.fromCharCode((n & 0x000000FF) >>>  0);
}
```

Comment: That returns an array of numbers; unfortunately, I need a string.

Comment: @TommyMcGuire I'll add an example of how to do that too.

Comment: That ought do it, I think. When I convert a number to a string using that method, I can convert it back to the same number. But the server is reporting something different. I must have something else wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Simplified version http://jsfiddle.net/eZsTp/ :

```
function dot2num(dot) { // the same as ip2long in php
    var d = dot.split('.');
    return ((+d[0]) << 24) +  
           ((+d[1]) << 16) + 
           ((+d[2]) <<  8) + 
            (+d[3]);
}

function num2array(num) {
     return [
        (num & 0xFF000000) >>> 24,
        (num & 0x00FF0000) >>> 16,   
        (num & 0x0000FF00) >>>  8,
        (num & 0x000000FF)
       ];    
}

function htonl(x)
{
     return dot2num(num2array(x).reverse().join('.')); 
}

var ipbyte = dot2num('12.34.56.78');
alert(ipbyte);
var inv = htonl(ipbyte);
alert(inv + '=' + num2array(inv).join('.'));
```

Comment: htonl is returning a number; I need a string. Let me add an example to the question.

Comment: @TommyMcGuire What kind of a string? If you have a string originally - `alert('String'.split('').reverse().join(''));`